# Sphere moving at relativistic velocities

Tags: special-relativity

I stumbled upon this exercise on a SR book:
Determine how fast a sphere of diameter 2R has to move to pass through a hole of diameter d on a planar surface.

If I understand correctly, this should not be possible because no mater how fast we are moving in one direction (a boost in the x direction w.l.o.g), the lengths of the sphere measured in the z and y axis will continue to be the same and won't suffer from length contraction. Am I missing something or the exercise is just that trivial?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: My reaction is the same as yours. I think it is "just that trivial" to someone who actually understands a little SR -- but understanding a little SR may not be so trivial!

Comment: I would reject any problem, on principle, that labels a diameter $R$.

Comment: @JEB, to be fair, the diameter is labeled 2R, so the radius would be R as expected.

Comment: @R.Elder was that 2 always there? If yes, than I'll just protest the phrasing of the question, though less vigorously.

Comment: No problem : $d > 2R$. It would be helpful if you posted the entire question as printed.

Comment: Your understanding is spot on: a Lorentz boost transforms only the spatial co-ordinate along the direction of relative motion. Could you please add the text of the question and a citation? I'd like to know whether it is worded such that a "trick" trivial answer (i.e. it's not possible) is implied; otherwise it's a misleading question  that could sabotage students' understanding - it would be a good catch on your part and would warrant a community Wiki answer to confirm.

Comment: Since you appear to be a fairly new user and might not be aware that @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance is pretty much always right, I'd like to confirm that he is certainly right in this case.

Comment: @WillO Thanks, *BLUSH*, although I'm a little concerned for readers of the textbook.